# Update data without retrieving

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Can NHibernate update some (not all) fields in the table row without retrieving any data?
I know Id of the entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all the examples here:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct

Answer (score 4):

```
session.CreateQuery("update Foo f set f.Date = :date where f.Id = :id")
    .SetParameter("date", DateTime.Now)
    .SetParameter("id", 25)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HQL

Comment: Can you give me an example, please. I don't know, where to write hql and how to perform it.